# PHP: The behavior of unparenthesized expressions containing both '.' and '+'/'-' will change in PHP 8: '+'/'-' will take a higher precedence

Tags: php

I am getting the following warning in my PHP script

**The behavior of unparenthesized expressions containing both '.' and '+'/'-' will change in PHP 8: '+'/'-' will take a higher precedence**

The code works though, the PHP version on the server is: PHP 7.4.33, is there a problem with the code?

```
    array_push($data, "" . str_getcsv($row)[0] . "," . str_getcsv($row)[1] . "," . str_getcsv($row)[2] . "," . str_getcsv($row)[3] + 1);
```

Comment: No, like the3 error says it's just a warning. If the server upgrades to PHP 8 it won't work as expected. You can make it unambiguous by just adding parenthesis like the warning suggests.

Comment: @mousetail The code will work as expected in PHP 8, without a warning, because string concatenation will have a lower precedence than arithmetic addition/subtraction. However, the code is ambiguous, and that's never a good thing. Adding parenthesis is the prudent thing to do.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware You are correct, this code actually won't work in PHP 7

Comment: @mousetail That's what I was thinking, yet the question states it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the this to explicitly set precedence, see if warning is clear.

```
array_push($data, "" . str_getcsv($row)[0] . "," . str_getcsv($row)[1] . "," . str_getcsv($row)[2] . "," . (str_getcsv($row)[3] + 1));
```